# System32 Hosts file modification

Tags: windows, system32

I am wondering if I can modify system32 hosts file using a google chrome extension? if not what other way can I modify the file without the need to access the file every time I want to edit it?

Comment: Modifying the hosts file requires Administrator privileges, and you can't change a file without accessing it. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to block a website site using google chrom extension such that the hosts file gets modified based on what the extension blocked

Comment: I think you may be looking for [this question on manipulating hosts file with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602460/powershell-to-manipulate-host-file) and [more details on regularly updating hosts file with administrator privileges](http://superuser.com/questions/725331/how-to-add-remove-lines-from-the-hosts-file).