# Replace whole string if part of the string is "not correct"

Tags: powershell

i need to make a script for "check/replace/add string to the file.
The "correct" string is "google.com 44.10.15.9" I have a part of the script for adding the whole line, but i don't know how to make it check other options, If the string would be there but only "google.com" without address or with wrong address.
My work looks like this.

```
$file= 'C:\Users\fialbvoj\Desktop\testPS.txt'
$name=" google.com "
$IP=" 44.10.15.9 "
$line="google.com 44.10.15.9"
$search=(Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern 'google.com 44.10.15.9').Matches.Success

if ($search ) {"Success"
} else {
    Add-Content -Path $file -Value $line
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: If you’re editing the Windows “hosts” file, there’s a load of examples in this question that you might be able to build something from… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602460/powershell-to-manipulate-host-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) accepts [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for the `-Pattern` parameter which allows you to use a [regular expression for the IPAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284147/1701026) instead of a literal IP address, e.g.:

```
 ... |Select-String 'google\.com ((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}'
```

To replace the any pattern with the "correct string" (aka IP address):

```
(Get-Content $file) -Replace 'google\.com ((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}', 'google.com 44.10.15.9' |Set-Content $file
```

**Note 1:** the parenthesis around `(Get-Content $file)` are only required if you need to write back to the same file.
**Note 2:** the backslash in `google\.com` is required to escape the dot which normally represents *any character* in a regular expression.